# Generic way to select "other value"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a dict that contains only two values:

```
foo = {'bar':someThing, 'foobar':someThingElse}
```

and I am given in a function `foo` and a `key` which can be either `bar` or `foobar`:

is there a generic way to select the *other* element? This function should use the knowledge that $foo$ only contains only two elements.

The hard coded way would be

```
def funnyStuff(foo, key):
    if key == 'bar':
        myKey = 'foobar'
    if key == 'foobar':
        myKey = 'bar'
    return foo[myKey]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(python2 only, and breaks when there are not exactly 2 key/value pairs)

```
foo.values()[not foo.keys().index(key)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only two elements? You don't need a `dict` then.

```
foo = {'bar':'someThing', 'foobar':'someThingElse'}

def selectOther(data, key):
  # structure unpacking is almost like pattern matching!
  [(k1, v1), (k2, v2)] = data.items()
  if k1 == key:
    return v2
  elif k2 == key:
    return v1
  else:
    raise KeyError("Your %r is not among data keys!" % key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
def funnyStuff(foo, key):
    return foo[[x for x in foo if x != key][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
foo = {'bar':'someThing', 'foobar':'someThingElse'}
def get_other(foo, key):
    return foo.get([k for k in foo.keys() if k != key][0])

print get_other('bar')
```

#### Output:

```
'someThingElse'
```

Although this works, it is inefficient since we create a list from another list, just to get to the `0th` item!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do this idea could be useful, make a new mapping from your keys to boolean, so that it is easy to negate them:

```
keys2bool = dict(zip(foo.keys(), [True, False]))
bool2values = dict(zip([True, False], foo.values()))

>>> bool2values[not keys2bool['bar']]
'someThingElse'
```

Answer (score 0):

foo = {'bar':'someThing', 'foobar':'someThingElse'}

def funnyStuff(foo, key):

```
    mykey = ""
    key_list = foo.keys()
    if key == key_list[0]:
            mykey = key_list[1]
    else:
            mykey = key_list[0]
    return mykey
```

print foo[funnyStuff(foo, 'foobar')]